# Incorrect sending values from html form to java

Tags: java, html, servlets, httprequest

I write servlet. I have such field in the forms:

```
<p>
   Car size: <input type="number" name="car_size" min = "2" max = "5" step = "1" value = "2" required/>
</p>
```

For example I've entered 2 figure. Then in java code I want to write this value in `Integer` variable:

```
Integer carSize = request.getIntHeader("car_size");
```

But then I see in that variable `carSize` `-1` value. How to fix it?

Comment: It isn't a header. It's a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the parameter from the request

```
Integer carSize = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("car_size"));
```

To make a request you should wrap the input field with a form tag and use this form to submit data in input fields.